# How to avoid printing logger main class name always, while printing logs?

Tags: java, logging

I want to print the log in console. I am using **java.util.logging.Logger** class to print the log. Below is my code.

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import com.practice.exception.InvalidOperationException;

public final class Log {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Log.class.getSimpleName());
    private Log() {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Object creation is not allowed.");
    }
    public static void logInfo(String pattern, Object...arguments) {
        MessageFormat format = new MessageFormat(pattern);
        String message = format.format(arguments);
        logger.info(message);
    }
}
```

I am using Log.logInfo() method to print the log. My question is when I am printing the log it is always printing in below format. I do not want to print 
**"Apr 20, 2019 1:06:14 PM com.practice.utils.Log logInfo"** every time I print some logs. Is there any way we can achieve this?

```
Apr 20, 2019 1:06:14 PM com.practice.utils.Log logInfo
INFO: First text I have entered.
Apr 20, 2019 1:06:14 PM com.practice.utils.Log logInfo
INFO: Second text I have entered.
```

Answer (score 0):

See a few suggestions here:
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/logging/customizing-default-format.html

The very easiest would be (from the link):

```
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", "[%1$tF %1$tT] [%4$-7s] %5$s %n");
```

Or even simpler (to just print log level and message):

```
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", "%4$s: %5$s %n");
```

Comment: Thank you @Stefan It works properly. But I did not understand what "%4$s: %5$s %n" does.

Comment: The logging package makes a call to String.format(template, ...) where you've now specified the template. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html
(%4$s means "insert the 4th argument (level), %5$s means "5th argument" and %n means "newline")

Answer (score 0):

can define format in configuration file.
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format= [%p] %t: %m

where
message     %m
level/severity  %p
thread  %t